# This reads EOFError: Ran out of input

Tags: python, class, pickle

This is a class I created

```
import pickle

class CarRecord:
    def __init__(self):
        self.VehicleID = ""
        self.Registration = ""
        self.DateOfRegistration = None
        self.EngineSize = 0
        self.PurchasePrice = 0.00

ThisCar = CarRecord()
Car = [ThisCar for i in range(5)]
Car[0].EngineSize = 2400
Car[1].EngineSize = 2300
Car[2].EngineSize = 2200
Car[3].EngineSize = 2100
Car[4].EngineSize = 2000
```

I want to write these records to the binary file

```
CarFile = open('Cars.DAT', 'wb')
for i in range(5):
   pickle.dump(Car[i], CarFile)
print(Car)

CarFile.close()
CarFile = open('Cars.DAT', 'rb')
Car = []

print("££££££££")
```

and append the record to he end of the list

```
while True:
```

and here I check for the end of file

```
Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile))
CarFile.close()
print(Car)
```

Comment: Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile)) CarFile.close() print(Car)

Comment: that goes under the while True:

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to call `pickle.dump` multiple times on one file object. Try taking all of the objects you want to dump, and putting them in a single list. Then dump that list just once into the file.

Comment: They are already in a single list called `Car`, I think you just need to do `pickle.dump(Car,CarFile)` without any loops then `Car.extend(pickle.load(CarFile))` again without loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code, the problem with your code is you are doing a while True, which is resulting in EOF, you need to either specify unpickling length, or handle for EOFError, as specified in the edit.

```
import pickle

class CarRecord:
    def __init__(self):
        self.VehicleID = ""
        self.Registration = ""
        self.DateOfRegistration = None
        self.EngineSize = 0
        self.PurchasePrice = 0.00

ThisCar = CarRecord()
Car = [ThisCar for i in range(5)]
Car[0].EngineSize = 2400
Car[1].EngineSize = 2300
Car[2].EngineSize = 2200
Car[3].EngineSize = 2100
Car[4].EngineSize = 2000

CarFile = open('Cars.DAT', 'wb')
for i in range(0,5):
    pickle.dump(Car[i], CarFile)
print(Car)

CarFile.close()
CarFile = open('Cars.DAT', 'rb')
Car = []

print("here")

for i in range(0,5):
    Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile))

CarFile.close()
print(Car)
```

EDIT:- I Found a better answer, which does not use hardcoded values. [Reading from a file using pickle and for loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871388/reading-from-a-file-using-pickle-and-for-loop-in-python)

I will post the answer here as well. Basically it catches EOFError and UnpicklingError so that, when file ends, it just closes, and you can use it normally as you want to

```
Car = []
CarFile = open('Cars.DAT', 'rb')
while 1:
    try:
        Car.append(pickle.load(CarFile))
    except (EOFError, UnpicklingError):
        break
CarFile.close()
```